# MySQL very slow query with custom function in spite of LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following table

```
id INT UNSIGED PRIMARY KEY
attrib1 INT
attrib2 INT
creationTime TIMESTAMP
```

And I have a function, that calculates very sophisticated result out of the attributes. It can be parametrized by a value from outside, thus I can not store the result as another attribute. Also, the funciton is not deterministic.

```
MY_FUNC(param1, attrib1, attrib2)
```

Now I want to get last 15 rows (ordered by timestamp) and I want to have the results of `MY_FUNC` as well. I tried:

```
SELECT *, MY_FUNC(2, attrib1, attrib2) FROM myTable ORDER BY creationTime LIMIT 0, 15;
```

Hovewer, this query is executing very long (> 2s when table has > 5000 rows).

I have come up with a hack:

```
SELECT *, MY_FUNC(2, attrib1, attrib2) FROM (
   SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY creationTime LIMIT 0, 15
) AS temp;
```

Which works, and works fast (< 0.1s for the same table). But I don't like this solution.

I suppose that in the first query MySQL runs `MY_FUNC` for every record, not only for the 15 I'm querying for. Am I right? Is there a way to configure MySQL/query so the function is calculated only for selected rows? Why MySQL calculates it for all of them although these results are useless?

I understand that they wouldn't be useless if they were used in `WHERE` or `ORDER` clause. But they are not.

Comment: You should have an index on creationTime, however, since your second query executes quickly, I expect this is not your issue.

Comment: Execute `EXPLAIN SELECT *, MY_FUNC(2, attrib1, attrib2) FROM myTable ORDER BY creationTime LIMIT 0, 15;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why does MySQL calculate the function for all rows?  That is how databases work (and not just MySQL).  The `ORDER BY` clause is applied to the result set *after* the `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING` clauses are processed.  In order to create the result set, the values have to be processed for all rows.  The `LIMIT` is applied to the results of the `ORDER BY`.

You have come across the way to get the performance you want:

```
SELECT t.*, MY_FUNC(2, attrib1, attrib2)
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM myTable t
      ORDER BY creationTime
      LIMIT 0, 15
     ) t;
```

This is not a "hack", but a very reasonable approach to solving your problem.  A parameter that changed the way that MySQL -- and all other database engines -- do this processing.  That would be a hack.

As a note:  an index on `myTable(creationTime)` would help the performance of this query, if you do not have one.