# Is there a way to write this SQL in HQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I need to run this query in MySQL using Hibernate (HQL):

```
SELECT t.atrib2, MY_FUNC(attrib1), MY_FUNC(attrib2), o.atrib1
       FROM (SELECT t.atrib1, t.atrib2, t.atrib3,o.atrib1
             FROM myTable t JOIN otherTable o
                  ON O.ID = T.O_ID   
                  ORDER BY creationDate
                  LIMIT 0, 100000) t;
```

I can not use a SELECT like this:

```
SELECT t.atrib2, MY_FUNC(attrib1), MY_FUNC(attrib2), o.atrib1
       FROM myTable t JOIN otherTable o
       ON o.ID = t.o_ID   
       ORDER BY creationDate
       LIMIT 0, 100000;
```

Because MySQL applies the function MY_FUNC to all rows when joining the table, and this gets too slow, like on thread: 
[MySQL very slow query with custom function in spite of LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626305/mysql-very-slow-query-with-custom-function-in-spite-of-limit) .

How would I properly write the first query in this post using HQL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes in hibernate you can use SQLQuery to write SQL query instead of HQL.
like:

```
 String sql = "select * from User" ;
  SQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this by using persistence Api's
"*entityManager.createNativeQuery*" or "*entityManager.createQuery*" as

String queryString = "*SELECT t.atrib2, MY_FUNC(attrib1), MY_FUNC(attrib2), o.atrib1 
FROM (SELECT t.atrib1, t.atrib2, t.atrib3,o.atrib1 
FROM myTable t JOIN otherTable o ON O.ID = T.O_ID ORDER BY creationDate LIMIT 0, 100000) t*";
*javax.persistence.Query query =  entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString)*;